# remote connect to mysql database in cpanel

Tags: c#, mysql, connection-string, cpanel

I have an app in C# and i want to remote connect to mysql database in cpanel 
my code is :

```
static string MyConString = SERVER= remoteDomin.com;DATABASE=XXX;UID=XXX;PASSWORD=XXX;";
MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConString);
```

but this cann't succeed and throw `MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException` :

> Access denied for user 'XXXr'@'adsl-109-74-46-204.dynamic.yemennet.ye'
>   (using password: YES)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean "in cpanel?"  Is your MySQL server running at a hosting provider?  Is your client on your local machine?  If so, that means you're trying to connect between your MySQL client and the server via the public internet.  It certainly looks like this is what you're trying to do.

A lot of hosting providers don't allow this. Yours does, because the message you're getting says that the MySQL server is rejecting your particular connection request.

You need to grant access privileges in your MySQL data base so

```
XXXr@%
```

or maybe

```
XXXr@adsl-109-74-46-204.dynamic.yemennet.ye
```

can get access to your database.  The first choice grants access to the user XXXr attempting to connect from any host.  The second mentions the hostname that goes with your current ADSL access IP number.

If you can't figure out how to grant this user privilege (also known as user access) via your cpanel, ask you hosting provider's tech support for help.

It's possible your hosting provider -- the service that runs the MySQL server and provides cpanel access to it -- won't allow this.  It's generally considered somewhat insecure to allow MySQL database connections from the public internet.

Comment: I mean " cpanel" Is my a hosting provider . And I grant access privileges in my MySQL to  the user XXXr . And I add my IP Address as Remote Database Access Hosts .But this cann't succeed!

Comment: CPANEL is not a hosting provider company, it is a well-known software package used by many hosting provider companies.  MySQL access is granted not to XXXr, or just a user, but to XXXr@hostname.  This is XXXr@localhost  sometimes, or it can be XXXr@% (meaning any host).  Most hosting providers that offer CPanel access do not allow access to their MySQL database servers except from the web servers they operate.

Comment: Thank you @Ollie Jones but how can grant access privileges in  MySQL to the user to XXXr@hostname in  hosting providers that offer CPanel access .

Comment: Ask your hosting provider company.  Each one does it differently.